# How to refactor this code to reduce duplication?

Tags: reactjs

```
    constructor(component) {
        this.component = component;
        utils.REACT.bindClassToMethods(this, [
            'clearExtended',
            'searchPrice',
            'searchAddress',
            'searchExtended',
            'expandSearchInit',
            'allSubTypes',
            'initCustomCheckbox',
            'updateAddressFromAutocomplete',
            'onChangeOrganisationId'
        ]);

        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
            sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
            sParameterName,
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] === 'filter' && sParameterName[1] === 'sold') {
                this.component.setState({
                    defaultFilter: true,
                    searchQuery: 'sold'
                });
            }
            if (sParameterName[0] === 'filter' && sParameterName[1] === 'leased') {
                this.component.setState({
                    defaultFilter: true,
                    searchQuery: 'leased'
                });
            }
        }
        {
            (component.state.defaultFilter === true && component.state.searchQuery === 'sold')
                ? this.component.setState({ defaultValue: ["Sold"] })
                : (component.props.is_tab !== undefined && component.props.is_tab === true)
                    ? this.component.setState({ defaultValue: ["Active", "Current", "Under Offer", "Sold", "Off Market", "Withdrawn", "Leased", "Draft"] })
                    : component.props.admin.length > 0 ? this.component.setState({ defaultValue: ["Active", "Current", "Under Offer"] }) : this.component.setState({ defaultValue: ["Active", "Current", "Under Offer", "Draft"] })
        }
        {
            (component.state.defaultFilter === true && component.state.searchQuery === 'leased')
                ? this.component.setState({ defaultValue: ["Leased"] })
                : (component.props.is_tab !== undefined && component.props.is_tab === true)
                    ? this.component.setState({ defaultValue: ["Active", "Current", "Under Offer", "Sold", "Off Market", "Withdrawn", "Leased", "Draft"] })
                    : component.props.admin.length > 0 ? this.component.setState({ defaultValue: ["Active", "Current", "Under Offer"] }) : this.component.setState({ defaultValue: ["Active", "Current", "Under Offer", "Draft"] })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you can do is merge the `setStates()`:

```js
if (sParameterName[0] === 'filter' && (sParameterName[1] === 'sold' || sParameterName[1] === 'leased')) {
    this.component.setState({
        defaultFilter: true,
        searchQuery: sParameterName[1],
    });
}

// Better with array
if (sParameterName[0] === 'filter' && ['sold', 'leased'].includes(sParameterName[1])) {
    this.component.setState({
        defaultFilter: true,
        searchQuery: sParameterName[1],
    });
}
```

Not entirely sure what the block after the for loop does though, but perhaps you could use the same logic on there.